# Virtualizing SharePoint on vSphere and Hyper-V

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, virtual-machine

I am planning on virtualizing my *SharePoint* environment and currently, I can go with either *VMware vSphere* or *Microsoft Hyper-V*.

I want to know whether one of the products works better with *SharePoint* than the other. I take it that *Hyper-V* might have more features since both are *Microsoft* products but I am really not sure.

So which one should I use?

Comment: Hello @Saleh Omar, Your feedback is very important 1. Are the below answers didn't helped you? 2. Do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with these clarifications, else please upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Practically,**  both will work properly with SharePoint, the two products are the same in terms of max configurations.

For comparison check [Choosing between VMware and Hyper-V](https://vinfrastructure.it/2016/11/microsoft-hyper-v-2016-vs-vmware-vsphere-6-5/)

---

**I prefer the Hyper-V for the following reasons:**

- Deploying new virtual servers in short times (Minutes).
- In many cases, there is no downtime for maintenance.
- The backup process is very easy.
- Low price.
- The live migration is simple.

Meanwhile, I prefer the Vmware for its known stability.